# System.Threading.ThreadAbortException on generic redirection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, generics, redirect

I am working on an `ASP.Net` project where we have an `centralized redirection method`. But some times it throws an exception:

> System.Threading.ThreadAbortException

The main problem is that often the code execution is not stopping after calling `SBA.Redirect("AnotherPage.aspx")` and the following code is still executing.

My generic function:

```
public static class SBA
{   
        public static void Redirect(string Url)
        {
                try
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(Url, false);
                    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();                
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (ex.GetType() != typeof(System.Threading.ThreadAbortException))
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I protected the `redirection` using the code below. It's working.

```
public static class SBA
{

    public static void Redirect(string Url)
    {
        try
        {
            //redirect only when 'IsRequestBeingRedirected' is false
            if (!HttpContext.Current.Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected)
            {
                Uri uri = null;
                bool isUriValid = Uri.TryCreate(Url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out uri);

                if (!isUriValid)
                {
                    throw new SecurityException("Invalid uri " + Url);
                }

                //Below check is not required but checked
                //to make obsolate security check 
                if (uri.OriginalString == null)
                {
                    throw new SecurityException("Invalid uri " + Url);
                }

                // check if host is from configured trusted host list
                if (uri.IsAbsoluteUri)
                {
                    var tempAppSetting = ConfigBLL.GetAppSetting(AppSettingSectionType.OtherSetting).Other;
                    if (!tempAppSetting.RedirectTrustedUrls.Contains(uri.Host))
                    {
                        throw new SecurityException("Untrusted url redirection detected. Can not redirect.");
                    }
                }

                var tempUrl = uri.OriginalString;

                //Few more logical check 

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(tempUrl, true);
            }
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.GetType() != typeof(System.Threading.ThreadAbortException))
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Redirect` raises a `ThreadAbortException` specifically in order to stop any following code from being run.

You are handling the `ThreadAbortException`.

Thus the following code is being run.

If you don't want the following code to be run, don't handle the `ThreadAbortException`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make the following call to make a redirect:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(Url);
```

There are two problems with your code:

- You use an overload of `Redirect` where you decide to **not** end the response by supplying `false` for the `endResponse` parameter. Hence the code after the redirect executes.
- You try to catch `ThreadAbortException`. When using the normal redirect as described above this exception is thrown. It is not an error condition but simply a way for ASP.NET to ensure proper termination of the current request. You can catch the exception but it is rethrown at the end of the catch block so your catch block will not do anything useful.

Because an exception is thrown when redirecting you should be aware of the following explained in the comment:

```
void HandleRequest() {
  try {
    Response.Redirect(" ... url ... ");
  }
  catch (Exception) {
    // Code here will execute after the redirect.
  }
}
```

To avoid problems the best thing is to catch a more specific exception type in the catch handler or at least not do anything in the handler that interferes with the redirect (like writing to the response stream).

Comment: What you suggested @Martin is actually a abbr of Response.Redirect method .. they both are same..:(

Comment: @MoumitMondal: I am not sure I understand your comment, but you supply `false` for the `endResponse` parameter. The overload with a single parameter will call the overload you are using with `true` for the `endReponse` parameter ensuring that the response ends by throwing the exception.